# No file was supplied for reference XXX.dacpac; deployment might fail

Tags: x86, platform, dacpac

I have a DacPac project that references several other dacpac projects. The referencing dacpac builds into an application directory that is harvested into a Wix Installer using Parrafin. All the referencing and referenced projects build fine. Multiple times today, when I attempted to deploy my referencing dacpac database, I got several an instance of this error per reference:

`No file was supplied for reference XXX.dacpac; deployment might fail.`

So far, I have:

- checked the installation directory: found none of the referenced dacpacs present.
- cleaned and rebuilt the dacpacs: No issues
- compared database project settings between these dacpacs and others that work as expected
- rebuilt the Wix installer again in case it was a fluke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of my application has a platform target of `x86` so I changed the referencing dacpac project's platform target to from `AnyCPU` to `x86` and it instantly worked as expected.

Comment: Dacpac's arent built with any specific bitness, but if your project build configuration (VS Build Menu -> Project Configuration) doesnt build a project based on those selections it would explain the missing dacpac